# Can't build OMNeT++ Project

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, omnet++

I can't build the basic project configuration and I am always getting this message in the console. I have set PREFER_CLANG=no as well and still getting this error.

```
16:09:44 **** Build of configuration debug for project Ihab Project ****
make MODE=debug all 
Computer.cc
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//Ihab
g++.exe: error: Project_dbg.exe: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:95: out/gcc-debug//Ihab] Error 1
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

16:09:46 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.705ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem, you can't put Spaces when you name your Project. I have renamed it to be **IhabTest** instead of **Ihab Project**.

```
19:44:44 **** Build of configuration debug for project IhabTest ****
make MODE=debug all 
Computer.cc
Creating executable: out/clang-debug//IhabTest_dbg.exe

19:44:47 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.826ms)
```